# Google Sheets query rows containing commas

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I've a column `Colors` that contains rows of colors. I've a query I'm using that I want to include getting the colors based on a cell the user will input. For example the user will input `Blue, Black` and I want my query to return rows 2, 4, 5 along with the conditions in my query.

I'm stuck on how to do it as I would need to parse the commas in order to get each individual colors. I've tried creating a function in the query but that doesn't work and neither is creating a function that includes my whole query.

[image]

`=QUERY('Sheet 1'!A1:D13, "select * where (AA contains 'Car' AND {*Return rows containing Blue and Black*})")`

Edit: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I want to be able to capture user's input on `D2` and include it in my query to return the rows that has "Car" in column AA and contains either or both of the colors "Blue" and "Black"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({A2:B}, 
 "where lower(Col1) matches '.*"&REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(D1), ", ?", ".*|.*")&".*' 
    and 1=1")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This works and it's what I'm looking for, however it would be great if there's explanations on each part of the regex.

Comment: sure, with regex we replace comma or comma followed by empty space (question mark acts in this case as "or") with a vertical straight line which also means slightly different "or" and because A column can contain more values than searched we add `.*` before and after to switch to partial mode instead of exact

Answer (score 1):

You can use REGEXMATCH

The function returns true if the argument is a substring of your string.

`=IF(REGEXMATCH(A_, Black"), 1, 0)`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear on my answer, I've updated my question. How would I include REGEXMATCH in my query to do what I'm looking for?